# Trigonometry Angle Addition and Subtraction

Tags: trigonometry, arithmetic, angle

I'm working on a problem.

[image]

The problem is boxed in Blue. Ignore the right side boxed in green, it's unreleated. Inside the blue box, I have highlighted in green where my error is when solving this problem.

This problem is from a website, and I'm a little confused, as to why my answer (boxed in red) is wrong. I've used Desmos.com and my answer is indeed wrong. It seems that I'm not understanding how the + and - signs are working? to get the first part of my answer inside of the error box I used the special angle identities.

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: $\sin(30^o)=1/2$ and $\cos(30^o=\sqrt{3}/2)$

Comment: This is not legible, at least not by me.  Please type your questions.

Comment: @pBlack Now that you know what your mistake was, you may respond to your own question.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.